# Ask Question opens with my previous question populating the title and question boxes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions

I am trying to post a new question on the site, but whenever I click the "ask question" link, I get the question page where the title and main boxes already populated with the question I asked yesterday! I closed and reopen the tab but it did not help. WTF?

Specifically, if I clean the question and enter the new one, it will actually change the old question and replace the text with the new text, right?? (It will be funny to see answers and comments totally unrelated to the question...)

UPDATE: Just verified that this happens in IE7 and not only in FF4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing a draft saved.

We save 1 draft per user, per site, 1 for Q and 1 for A.

These drafts are normally cleared when you successfully submit a Q or A. Sounds like that didn't happen in your case, but you can just delete the pre-filled draft text.

Comment: OK, thanks Jeff. This confirms that I can go on and overwrite the filled text.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is a feature, not a bug - it saves a draft occasionally, which allows you to go off and read some of the suggested similar questions without losing your hard crafted question.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you??? This is the first time I see this behavior, and it prevents me from typing in a new question, so how exactly is this considered a feature? Am I missing something?

Comment: Usually when opening similar questions based on the auto suggestions, I open them in a new tab, so I don't lose the typed title.